# Magento Upgrade from magento 1.4.1.0 to 1.9.1.0

Tags: magento, upgrade

I am new to Magento and I need to upgrade my magento 1.4.1.0 to 1.9.1.0. Anyone here who's done that before? I even looked for some tutorials but I couldn't find a reliable one. So I was just wondering if anyone here can provide a reliable suggestion or even a link to a tutorial that helped you before would be of great help.
Thank you everyone!!

Comment: You should not directly upgrade to 1.9.1.0, first upgrade to 1.5

Comment: After upgrading to 1.5, is it okay if I directly upgrade to 1.9 or should I go step by step like from 1.5 to 1.6 and then to 1.7 and so son

Comment: However you do it, make sure you do it through a test environment. Keep your live site running until you've upgraded the test environment. Then upgrade the live site (making sure you have a complete backup you can go back to if it goes wrong).

Answer (score 0):

Check this [Link](http://duntuk.com/magento-upgrade) , tell me if you have some troubles to following the tutorial or if you have other operate system